# django when adding data from admin interface: TypeError at admin/... unicode object not callable

Tags: python, django

I'm getting an error when trying to save to the following model using the admin interface:

models.py

```
class Answer(models.Model):
a = models.TextField(primary_key=True)
gloss = models.TextField(blank=True)  
clean = models.TextField(blank=True)  
count = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
p = models.IntegerField(blank=True)    
def __unicode__(self):
    return u"%s" % self.a    
class Meta:                                       
    db_table = u'answers'
```

here's the error message that shows up on the admin interface:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/admin/emotions/answer/add/

Django Version: 1.4 pre-alpha SVN-16322
Python Version: 2.6.2
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'emo20qBrowser.emotions']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/home/abe/bin/django-trunk/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args,     **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/abe/bin/django-trunk/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
  316.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/abe/bin/django-trunk/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  91.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/abe/bin/django-trunk/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  77.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/abe/bin/django-trunk/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  196.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/abe/bin/django-trunk/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  25.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/abe/bin/django-trunk/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  91.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/abe/bin/django-trunk/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  21.                 return func(self, *args2, **kwargs2)
File "/home/abe/bin/django-trunk/django/db/transaction.py" in inner
  211.                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/abe/bin/django-trunk/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in add_view
  871.             if form.is_valid():
File "/home/abe/bin/django-trunk/django/forms/forms.py" in is_valid
  121.         return self.is_bound and not bool(self.errors)
File "/home/abe/bin/django-trunk/django/forms/forms.py" in _get_errors
  112.             self.full_clean()
File "/home/abe/bin/django-trunk/django/forms/forms.py" in full_clean
  269.         self._post_clean()
File "/home/abe/bin/django-trunk/django/forms/models.py" in _post_clean
  331.             self.instance.clean()

Exception Type: TypeError at /admin/emotions/answer/add/
Exception Value: 'unicode' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I think I figured it out...  I'm using a variable/column called "clean".  Django's admin interface has a method called "clean()" also, which does some kind of validation.  It appears that there was some kind of naming conflict so I changed the variable to name to "cleaned" and then to make sure that it knows what database field to use (I'm using a legacy/preexisting db), I added a db_column option:

```
cleaned = models.TextField(blank=True,db_column="clean")
```

It would have been nice to know that "clean" was a reserved identifier in django but at least I only wasted half a day on this django stuff which ostensibly makes database operations easier. To be fair, I just started django this morning and if I would have found and answer on stackoverflow it would have been a breeze to fix.

If anyone knows a better way to handle this, let me know...

Comment: bummer... that's frustrating. Here is the documentation page showing what attributes / methods, etc a model has:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/instances/

Comment: Thanks, good to know!  I'm doing Django again 10 years later and saw this post again, here's @Aaron 's link updated, [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/instances/](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/instances/)